# Compare values in Different column and row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ID COl1 COl2
1  13    15
2  13    16
3  13    17
4  17    13
```

What I need is to select all rows where `Col1` value is available in `Col2` and vice versa.

This case only ROW 4 or ROW 3  should be returned. They have same values (13 17).

Take it as `col1` is Buyer and `col2` is Seller

I want to know who are the users who bought / sell from EACH OTHER.
if user a bought from user b, user b should buy from user a in order to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    yourTable   a
INNER JOIN
    yourTable   b
        ON  a.Col1 = b.Col2
        AND a.Col2 = b.Col1
        AND a.id  != b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col2) and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col2 = t.col1) ;
```

If you want them in the same row, I would still use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col2 AND t2.col2 = t.col1) ;
```

I recommend this over a self-join because it will not generate multiple rows if there are multiple examples of the buyers and sellers on either side.

Comment: @scryptopath - Then your query has a typo, or your data is different from that in the question (row 2 would only be returned if there's a 16 in col1 somewhere).

Comment: Yup, there is a 16 in col1 somewhere, but col2 isnt 13. i need same case as 13 17 - 17 13

Comment: @Scryptopath . . . That is not how I interpreted the question.  It is not at all clear that you want the results in the same row -- and your original typo suggested exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using sub queries:

```
SELECT ID, COl1, COl2
FROM table1 WHERE COl1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT COl2 FROM table1)
UNION
SELECT ID, COl1, COl2
FROM table1 WHERE COl2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT COl1 FROM table1)
```

Comment: Your solution doesnt respect the objective of them being bought from each other. If we have 13 in col1 and 17 in col2, then we should have 17 in col1 and 13 in col2 in another row

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE
col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM your_table) 
AND 
col2 IN (SELECT col1 FROM your_table);
```